# highest voted unanswered questions is showing answered questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

When I click the unanswered box, then click votes, I find a list of questions which do have answers to them.

This is the Url which describes this:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes

Shouldn't it show the *unanswered* questions with the highest votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of an uanswered question is a question without answer or *a question with one or more answers without one or more upvotes*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. :)